# Запись данных в значение объекта

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать подобие строительного калькулятора где будут вписаны данные. До конца не могу понять 1 вещь. Есть объект и в его значение нужно записать данные (все данные будут `number`).

Данные будут вписываться в `input`.

```
let house = {
  price: '',
  square:'',
  rooms:''
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так.

Доступ к полям объекта осуществляется по ключам, которые являются идентификаторами `input`ов

```
house[input.id] = +input.value;
```

```js
let house = {
  price: null,
  square: null,
  rooms: null
};

[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    house[input.id] = +input.value;
  });
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(house));
})
```

```css
label {
  width:60px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label for="price">price</label><input id="price"><br>
<label for="square">square</label><input id="square"><br>
<label for="rooms">rooms</label><input id="rooms"><br>
<button>done</button>
```